# Stucked with loops, steps and open/close tags

Tags: php, loops

```
$step=3;
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    if($i/$step===(int)($i/$step)){
        echo 'START:';
    }
    echo $i,'-';
    if($i>0 and $i/$step===(int)($i/$step)){
        echo ':END<BR>';
    }
}
```

I need result like this

```
START:0-1-2-:END
START:3-4-5-:END
START:6-7-8-:END
....
```

and so on, but can't figure out how to manage to achieve it.

Comment: use the modulo operator instead of complex comparisons

Comment: To add to what @greg0ire said, you want to use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%` in most languages), which returns the remainder when dividing the first argument by the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$step = 3;
for($i = 0 ; $i < 100; $i++){
    if($i % $step == 0){
        echo "START:";
    }
    echo $i."-";
    if(($i + 1) % $step == 0){
        echo ":END<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to demonstrate the power of array functions:

```
$numbers = range(0, 100);
$chunks = array_chunk($numbers, 3);
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
  echo 'START:', implode('-', $chunk), '-:END<BR>';
}
```

Comment: you are missing the `<BR>` after `-:END`. not absolutely necessary, but helps with readability. Also, OP's range would be `range(0,99)`

Comment: @Jason McCreary thanx, but it's not convinient for my task (there's a lot of code between 'start' and 'end' texts)

Comment: @E L, fair enough. Again just demonstrating the power of native array functions as I believe they are under used.

Comment: I personaly dont think that such a simple task needs array functions. Its an overkill in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo operator. it basicaly returns you the remaining of the division. For example, as $i becomes 20, its modulo will be 2 in this case (20/3=18) and 2 is the remaining part. As $i becomes 21, then there is nothing to remain as it divides perfectly by 3, thus 21%3 results 0. This way you can find out every third time to execute something.

Try this:

```
$step=3;

echo 'START:';

for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){

    if(!($i%$step) and $i>0){
         echo ':END<BR>START:';
    }
    echo $i,'-';
}

echo ':END<BR>';
```

Comment: wrong: START:0-:END
1-2-START:3-:END
4-5-START:6-:END
7-8-START:9-:END
10-11-START:12-:END
13-14-START:15-:END

Comment: the modified code is better, but you now have an extra `START::END` at the beginning - `START::END START:0-1-2-:END`

Comment: It is not extra. It is there so you do twice less calculations in the loop, which would make the code cleaner and somewhat faster

Comment: It is extra as it is always echoing out an empty `START::END` - `START::END START:0-1-2-:END START:3-4-5-:END START:6-7-8-:END ...`. Your code has less calculations, is cleaner, and somewhat faster, but it still has a redundant `START::END`.

Comment: @Sean you're right. better add the  "and $i>0" to the statement. Or, if zero is not needed than start the loop from 1 directly.